# Combo conditionals for filenames Python

Tags: python

I have a directory with the following sample filenames:

```
Apples.xlsx
Bananas.xlsx
Apples.docs
Pears.xlsx
```

I’m trying to form a list of only .xlsx files with either Apples or Bananas in the filename.

Tried this:

```
If (“Apples” or “Bananas”) and “.xlsx” in filename:
     Do something
```

But the resulting list of files is:

```
Apples.xlsx
Bananas.xlsx
Pears.xlsx
```

What an I missing?  Something rudimentary no doubt but Google and SO suggestions are not yielding the expected result:

```
Apples.xlsx
Bananas.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is not correct.

```py
if ("Apples" in filename or "Banana" in filename) and “.xlsx” in filename:
     Do something
```

Here you checked all the conditions. In your answer, you did ("apples" or "banana") which is true, and you checked if true in filename so the answer was not correct.

Comment: Thanks. So simple, yet so far away was I.